# disable "update cart" button and reenable when a user changes the quantity?

Tags: expresso-store

I know it's not really expresso-store related, but I hope that one of you girls can share some javascript magic to make this possible.

I want the "update cart" button to be disabled until a user changes the amount on the checkout page. to give the user a better clue of what she should be doing.

any help appreciated! 
cheers
stefan

Comment: You're probably more likely to get a good answer if you post what you have tried so far, and where you think it's going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do this with vanilla jQuery.

Set the update cart button as disabled by default:

```
<input type="submit" name="update_cart" value="Update Cart" id="store_update_cart" disabled />
```

Then make your item quantity fields have a class you can use to target them:

```
<input name="items[{key}][item_qty]" value="{item_qty}" class="store_item_qty" />
```

And use jQuery to enable the button when the value changes:

```
$(function() {
    $(".store_item_qty").update(function() {
        $("#store_update_cart").attr('disabled', false);
    });
});
```